# nested fields_for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i have problem permit about double nested fields_for on rals 4. example relationship:

```
  Service - > has_many :product_services
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_services, allow_destroy: true
  Product Service -> has_many :foto_product_services
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :foto_product_services, allow_destroy: true
```

Service -> new.html.slim

```
= form_for @service, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  = f.fields_for :product_services do |builder|
    = render 'field_product', f: builder
= f.submit
```

Service -> _field_product.html.slim

```
= f.text_field :price, :class => 'text_field input-lg width-100'
= f.fields_for :foto_product_services do |builder|
    = builder.file_field "avatar[]", type: :file, multiple: true
```

Permit Params in my Service Controller

```
def service_params
  params.require(:service).permit(:service_category_id, :title, :description, :product_services_attributes => [:title, "_destroy"], :foto_product_services_attributes => [:avatar])
end
```

When I click button submit after selected foto product, I get error unpermitted param :foto_product_services_attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You have deep nested attributes, so the `foto_product_services_attributes` should be inside the `product_services_attributes`:

```
params.require(:service).permit(:service_category_id, :title, :description, :product_services_attributes => [:title, "_destroy", :foto_product_services_attributes => [:avatar]])
```